# fetch csv file by using JS and display the data in chart Js

Tags: javascript

[that the image of error message][1]I have local cvs file and I try to fetch the data and display them in chart Js the problem that i can't read this data .This is the code

```
enter code here
```

**
``` 
const xlabel=[];
const ytemp=[];
chartIt();

```
        async function chartIt(){
           await getDatach();
       
        const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
        
        const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels:xlabel,
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'some data',
                    data: ytemp,
                    fill:false,
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)' ,
                    borderColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                    borderWidth: 1
                }]
            }
        });

    }
      
 async function getDatach(){

 const response = await fetch('ZonAnn.Ts+dSST.csv');
 const data=await response.text();

 const rows=data.split('\n').slice(1);
 table.forEach(row => {
    const columns=elt.split(',');
    const year=columns[0];
    xlabel.push(year);
    const temp=columns[1];
    ytemp.push( parseFloat (temp)+14);
    Console.log(year,temp);
});
```

}

```
**
  


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bK4Sq.png
```

Comment: can you include an error message (if that's what's happening)?

Comment: ok now I'll put a link for image error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it by using live server

```
<html>
    <head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.4/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="200"></canvas>

        <script>
            const xlabel=[];
            const ytemp=[];
            chartIt();
            
            async function chartIt(){
               await getDatach();
           
            const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
            
            const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'line',
                data: {
                    labels:xlabel,
                    datasets: [{
                        label: 'some data',
                        data: ytemp,
                        fill:false,
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)' ,
                        borderColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                        borderWidth: 1
                    }]
                }
            });

        }
          
     async function getDatach(){

     const response = await fetch('ZonAnn.Ts+dSST.csv');
     const data=await response.text();
 
     const table=data.split('\n').slice(1);
     table.forEach(row => {
        const columns=row.split(',');
        const year=columns[0];
        xlabel.push(year);
        const temp=columns[1];
        ytemp.push( parseFloat (temp)+14);
        
    });
    
 }
            </script>
       
    </body>
</html>
```